# How can i store binary data using redis-plus-plus like i want to store a structure? @for_stack?

Tags: c++, redis

In C, we use hiredis to store data in the form of binary by using %b specifier in redisCommand function, how can we do this in c++ using redis-plus-plus or any other alternative?

```
#include <sw/redis++/redis++.h>                                                                                                    
#include<iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
using namespace sw::redis;                                                                                                                 
using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
struct person                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                  
int age;                                                                                                                           
string name;                                                                                                                       
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
int main(){                                                                                                                        
person p1;                                                                                                                         
p1.age=18;                                                                                                                         
p1.name="Abhishek";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
try{                                                                                                                                       
auto redis_cluster = RedisCluster("tcp://127.0.0.1:30001");                                                                        
redis_cluster.set("person",StringView(&p1,size_t(sizeof(person))));                                                                
auto reply=redis_cluster.get("person");                                                                                            
if(reply){                                                                                                                                 
person* p2=*reply;                                                                                                                 
cout<<p2->age<<endl;                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                  catch(const Error &e){                                                                                                             cout<<"Error"<<endl;                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You can save the binary data into a `std::string` object, which is binary safe, and then pass the `std::string` object to redis-plus-plus's API.
2. If you already have a pointer to the binary data, and the length of the data, you can construct a `StringView` object, and pass it to redis-plus-plus's API.

```
std::string val = "this binary safe string contains your binary data";
redis.set("key", val);

const char *data = "pointer to your binary data";
size_t len = 100; // length of your binary data
redis.set("key", StringView(data, len));
```

If you still have any problem with redis-plus-plus, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/issues) on GitHub.

Comment: I have added my code, does the data in StringView object has to be of char* only?

Comment: @abhishekrawat You cannot save a pointer to a user defined data structure into Redis. Please check [this](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/issues/64) for detail.